# How to redirect user from controller to another domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to redirect the user to another website.domain.

Here's the controller:

```
public void LogOff(){...}
```

I tried `Server.Transfer("www.google.fr")` => Error executing child request for www.google.fr.

I tried `Redirect("www.google.fr");` => no page loading

I don't know what to make...

Comment: @Raphael thanks but yes, it doesn't work for me :-/

Comment: Why do you need to return void?  Return an ActionResult.

Comment: There are impacts if I change the return type, see this as a constraint!

Comment: What could they be?  Since it's void right now you're obviously not using the result anywhere.

Comment: @emodendrokey: there is a if(xxx){return redirect}, it doesn't redirect the user in all cases

Comment: Yeah, no problem.  It does something in any case, right?  ActionResult can be pretty much anything you would want to do from a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.fr"); is the working solution for my problem!

Comment: I'd argue the problem is of your own making since you insist on returning void for some reason.

Comment: Your action return type should be _ActionResult_

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to any url using `return Redirect()`:

```
public ActionResult LogOff()
{

    return Redirect("http://www.google.fr");

}
```

Comment: ok thankS but did you think that there is a method that allow me to let the public void LogOff(){...} controller?

Comment: from asp.net mvc action you can do this way but using _void_ return type i don't know if any way there for it